# Postback onchange with selected option value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to postback and pass in a parameter `onchange`.  I have

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>)@Model.PhaseNames, new { @onchange = "location.href='/Home/Index?phaseFilter=this.value;'" })
```

This nearly works.  `this.value` is not replaced with the selected option value as I would expect.  Also, is there a better way to create the URL in this case?

Comment: Try changing the href to `'/Home/Index?phaseFilter='+this.value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@Model.PhaseNames, new { @onchange = "location.href='/Home/Index?phaseFilter=' + this.value;" })
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanted to write the `onchange` part like this:

```
@onchange = "location.href='/Home/Index?phaseFilter=' + this.value;"
```